# Removing MC from array AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having a problem removing a MovieClip from an array.

I am getting this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Spiker/loop()".
```

The spike (Spiker) is getting removed, but the error still annoys me.. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is my code :

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Spiker extends MovieClip {

    public var spikeDirection:int = 1;
    private var removed = false;
    public function Spiker() {
        // constructor code
        trace("Spiker added");

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }
    private function loop (evt){
        this.x += spikeDirection * 10;

        for(var i:int = 0; i < this["parent"].enemyList.length; i++){
            if(removed == false){
                if(this["parent"].enemyList[i].hitTestObject(this)){
                    trace("Spikerhit");
                    removed = true;
                    remove(evt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function remove (evt){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        this["parent"].removeChild(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `this["parent"]` vs simply `parent`?

Comment: Well, sometimes only "parent" works, and sometimes it doesn't. It seems to me that "this["parent"]" work more often than only "parent" :) in this case "parent" will only work in front of "removeChild(this)", and not in front of "enemyList"

Comment: Hmm, the thing with `parent` is that it is `null` if the object does not in fact have a parent. There's no difference between `this["parent"]` and `parent` other than one takes longer to type and the other provides accurate code suggestions in a decent IDE. If you wrap everything that deals with the parent in `if (parent !== null)` you might find your error stops :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from your `for` loop, this line exactly :

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < this["parent"].enemyList.length; i++){
```

because when your current object has touched an `enemy` it is removed from its `parent`, and for the next iteration of the `for` loop (if there is one), `this["parent"]` is `null` and that's why that error is fired as the `for` loop is verifying every iteration the conditional statement that determines when the looping ends (`this["parent"].enemyList.length` in your case).

To avoid that, you can use a variable, for example, to store the number of `enemies` to be used in the `for` loop.

You can also use the [`break`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#break) statement inside your `for` loop after removing your object to exit that loop.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tested it yet, but i thought but had something to do with that line! (As you can see by my Boolean test..)